# How to round all the numbers in a function?

Tags: functional-style, number-representation

I have a complicated function that is a combination of floating-point numbers and variables. I want all the numbers rounded off, but I have no clue how to do this. For example I would want

```
f[x_,y_]:=3.23425124`x^2 + 5.8978587`y
```

To become

```
f[x_,y_]:=3.2x^2 + 5.9y
```

If it were an array I could have something like

```
Thread[Round[#],array]
```

But with a function what to do is not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
3.23425124` x^2 + 5.8978587` y /. Times[a_, b_] :> Times[Round[a, 0.1], b]
(*3.2 x^2 + 5.9 y*)
```

`coefficient * variable` is of `Times[coefficient, variable]` in full form, therefore you can use this pattern to match and round only the coefficient.

Comment: Awesome! How does it work...?

Comment: @quantum_loser Added to answer

Comment: It would be more versatile to do `/. a_?NumberQ :> Round[a, .1]` as the replacement rule, then it would catch numbers in the denominators and not just simple products.

Comment: @JasonB you are right, I didn't think much, only made it work with the example

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what exactly is an input but here's my interpretation:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, y_] := 3.23425124` x^2 + 5.8978587` y;

f[2, 3]
```

> ```
> 30.6306
> ```

```
DownValues[f] = DownValues[f] /. n_?NumericQ :> RuleCondition@Round[n, 0.1];

f[2, 3]
```

> ```
> 30.5
> ```